# How do i make my if statement stop repeating?

Tags: javascript

Ok so I am creating a small program to guess how much fingers a user has up but only 5 fingers is the max number of fingers.Therefore, if a user clicks a number higher than five it should prompt saying it doesn't check higher but when it does prompt the alert repeats and repeats

how do I stop it repeating? also please explain the reason it is repeating for me.

https://jsbin.com/hiniqiqobe/1/edit?html,js,output

//If you put a number over 5 it repeats the alert box

raw code:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>


<p>How many fingers are you holding up</p>
<input id="myNumber">
<button id="theGuess">Guess</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("theGuess").onclick=function(){

    var gotit = false;  var guesses = 1;    var x; var outOfControl = 6;
    while(gotit == false){
               x = Math.random();
               x = 6*x;
               x = Math.floor(x);

                if (document.getElementById("myNumber").value==x){



                 gotit=true;

                }else{

                guesses++;

                }
                if (document.getElementById("myNumber").value >= outOfControl){

                    alert("sorry i can only guess up to five");
                }
          }
          alert("i got it "+x+".it only tool me"+guesses+" guesses" );
  }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do while (something). The something is always true.

Comment: Try stepping through your program in the debugger.

Comment: You have another slight problem with you code. First you have a variable to control the guess number, then you have a static text "sorry i can only guess up to five".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("theGuess").onclick = function() {

  var gotit = false;
  var guesses = 1;
  var x;
  var outOfControl = 6;
  while (gotit == false) {
    x = Math.random();
    x = 6 * x;
    x = Math.floor(x);

    if (document.getElementById("myNumber").value == x) {



      gotit = true;

    } else {

      guesses++;

    }
    if (document.getElementById("myNumber").value >= outOfControl) {

      alert("sorry i can only guess up to five");
      return;
    }
  }
  alert("i got it " + x + ".it only tool me" + guesses + " guesses");
}
```

Add 'return' after the sorry alert

Your loop is suppose to run until gotit is NOT true. The script shows the alert but does not escape out of the while loop.

Comment: Thank you very much @LuckyChingi

Answer (score 2):

Actually what is happening is
you declared `gotit = false`
and you are not updating the vale of `gotit` which results in an infinite loop

you can prevent the infinite loop as suggested in @Lucky Chingi's answer